# Using a split-step fourier method for a radial equation

Tags: fourier-transform, heat-equation

I have the common heat equation:
$$\partial_tU=\nabla^2U$$
In one dimension I can solve it using a split-step fourier method:
$$U(x, t+\delta t)=F^{-1}\left(\exp(-i\delta tk^2)F(U)\right)$$
Now I know that in my case $U$ is radially symmetric, and in two dimensions:
$$\partial_tU=\left(\frac{1}{r}\partial_r+\partial^2_r\right)U$$
Is there a way to still use the equation above with a fourier transformation in one dimension, or do I have to convert the equation into a cartesian coordinate system
$$\partial_tU=\left(\nabla^2_x+\nabla^2_y\right)U$$
and apply a fourier transformation in two dimensions to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short solution was to use the hankel transformation instead of the fourier transformation.

Comment: Can you write out some detail about how you solved this? I have a similar question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3939079/768874 . Would be very much appreciated!